# Proof of the connection between V and Q in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I've been studying some basics RL in the [SpinningUp materials](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro.html).

Is there any mathematical proof that $V^\pi(s) = E_{a \sim \pi} [Q^\pi(s, a)|s_0 = s]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It follows very simply from the definitions of V and Q.

These are the relevant definitions:

$$G_t \space \dot{=} \space \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \gamma^k R_{t+k+1}$$

$$V^{\pi}(s) \space \dot{=} \space \mathbb{E}_{A \sim \pi}[G_t|S_t=s]$$

$$Q^{\pi}(s, a) \space \dot{=} \space \mathbb{E}_{A \sim \pi}[G_t|S_t=s, A_t=a]$$

You can ignore the definiton of return, $G_t$, I included it for completeness, and to simplify the other definitions.

The *only* difference between the definitions of V and Q is adding the selection of $a$ in the conditions. If you remove the action selection in the definition of Q, and condition it instead on following the policy, you are back to the definition of V.

You can also expand the expectation in the definition of V using the policy function to show the same thing:

$$V^{\pi}(s) = \mathbb{E}_{A \sim \pi}[G_t|S_t=s]$$

$$V^{\pi}(s) = \sum_{a}\pi(a|s) \mathbb{E}_{A \sim \pi}[G_t|S_t=s, A_t=a]$$

$$V^{\pi}(s) = \sum_{a}\pi(a|s) Q^{\pi}(s,a)$$

Convert this back to an expectation over the policy:

$$V^{\pi}(s) = \mathbb{E}_{A \sim \pi}[Q^{\pi}(S_t,A_t)|S_t=s]$$

Comment: I'm trying to convince myself about the marginal expectation you used.
By definition, we have:

$E_{\tau \sim \pi}[f(\tau)] = \int_\tau P(\tau|\pi)$ f(\tau)

$V^\pi(s) = E_{\tau \sim \pi}[R(\tau)|s_0=s]$

$Q^\pi(s, a) = E_{\tau \sim \pi}[R(\tau)|s_0=s, a_0=a]$


\


From marginal probability, we have that

$P(\tau|s_0=s) = \int_a P(\tau|s_0=s, a_0=a)$

\

And finally

$V^\pi(s) = \int_\tau P(\tau|s_0=s, \pi) R(\tau) = \int_\tau \int_a P(\tau|s_0=s, a_0=a, \pi) R(\tau) = \int_a \int_\tau P(\tau|s_0=s, a_0=a, \pi)R(\tau) = \int_aQ^\pi(s, a)$

But I'm missing something...

Comment: @fig0 I'm not familiar with that notation, but I agree you have made some kind of mis-step. Your very last expression should include some reference to $\pi(a|s)$ or its definition in the terms you are using $P(a|s_0=s)$ as a factor. Then it would be expressing the correct relationship